# Select multiple values from refreshing list with Selenium webdriver and C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I have a list with several values. Each time I select a value, the list is refreshed. How can I iterate through the list?

This is my code

```cs
     IList<IWebElement> program = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='PnlGAPAncillaryPrograms']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
     foreach (IWebElement option in program) 
                        {
                       if (option.Text.Contains(" Program name ")
                            {
                                var ddVehicle_Model_An = driver.FindElement(By.Name("GapToolsRepeater$ctl14$DdlCoverageTypes"));
                                var selectVehicle_Model_An = new SelectElement(ddVehicle_Model_An);
                                selectVehicle_Model_An.SelectByText("program name");
*///in this control page was refreshed//*
    
        }
    }
```

**program** - This list value is refreshed so for the next iteration I get a stale reference error. The `foreach` call throws the error after the first iteration.

How can I get the list value?

Comment: Where do you get the stale reference error? In the `FindElement` call for `ddVehicle_Model_An` or one of the other calls?

Comment: foreach (IWebElement option in program) in this line (program ) get that error....

Comment: list value is cleared once the page got refresh that was my problem.......

Comment: After the Findelement  call for  ddVehicle_Model_An  page will refresh  so the next iteration got error in foreach .....Program contains count12  TEXT was ""stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document""